# How to get the driver details of Dataedo connection for connection string?

Tags: python, oledb, microsoft-dynamics, oledbconnection

I have been provided with Dataedo access to Microsoft Dynamics 365 tables.
I am writing a python file to establish connection with those tables.

I am not able to find the exact driver details for this connection string.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import warnings

import yaml

from yaml.loader import SafeLoader


warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

connectionString = 'DRIVER={Devart ODBC Driver for Dynamics 365};SERVER=dataedo.XYZ.us-east-1.ABC.amazonaws.com;uid=ABC;pwd=ABC;DATABASE=MYDB;Trusted_connection=yes'

try:
    sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
    print("success")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The below is my error

`('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Please suggest me a solution for this.

I tried to establish the connection with dataedo of Microsoft Dynamics 365 tables

I couldnt get the connection established, using Python.

Thanks,
Sabarisri

Comment: Hey, I'll be happy to help, but you need to explain your issue more clearly. As far as I understand you want to connect to a Dynamics 365 instance using pyodbc. However, I don't get what Dataedo has to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified" is an incorrect ODBC driver name in the connection string. This situation occurs when the specified driver is not installed in the system or with errors.

Additionally, mistakes can be made in any character while specifying the driver's name. To ensure that the driver is correctly installed and to find out its correct name, you can use the ODBC Administrator program.